# featured content slider plugin

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins

I have used this plugin `"http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-featured-content-slider/"` in my web page. It works fine. But I am trying to stop the slider on mouse over. I am not knowledgeable in jQuery. I don't know how to change it, or in which place or which file to make the change.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The slider is initialised in content-slider.php in the plugin 
You can add the pause option to the list in there

pause:         0,     // true to enable "pause on hover"

e.g

```
jQuery('#featured_slider ul').cycle({ 
        fx: '<?php $effect = get_option('effect'); if(!empty($effect)) {echo $effect;} else {echo "scrollLeft";}?>',
        prev: '.feat_prev',
        next: '.feat_next',
        speed:  800, 
        timeout: <?php $timeout = get_option('timeout'); if(!empty($timeout)) {echo $timeout;} else {echo 4000;}?>, 
        pager:  null,
        pause: true
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

This plugin is based on the [jQuery cycle plugin by Mike Alsop](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/). The plugin itself has the `pause` option which enables 'pause on hover' but it doesn't look like the WP version of the plugin exposes this configuration option via the admin panel.

If you can find the script file in your theme that initialises the slider, you can set the option manually. Try searching your theme folder for `.cycle()` and that should give you the correct script file.